# SelectMethod called twice for ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repository-pattern, objectdatasource

as I am new to ASP.NET webforms and Entity framework, I am experimenting with a pet project.

During this I came across the following which I am trying to understand:

1. I have an ObjectDataSource (called `EmployerObjectDataSource`) that is using a method of business logic layer (BLL) object for selecting the data - the method is `GetEmployer`
2. In the `Page_PreRender` callback of my page, I call a method `populateFields` to populate the fields within a FormView
3. In the `populateFields` I call `EmployerObjectDataSource.Select()` to get the `Employer` record.
4. If there are any records returned, then I populate the text boxes with the values from the returned record.

Here is the code:

```
    //Following Dmytro's comment, I will use Page_Load instead, however this 
    //does not resolve the problem
    //protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _username = "Lefteris";
        _version = 1;

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            populateFields();
        }
    }

    private bool populateFields()
    {
        //IEnumerable<Employer> empl = ((IEnumerable<Employer>)EmployerObjectDataSource.Select()).ToList();

        //The GetEmployer method of BLL is called here (as expected)
        List<Employer> empl = (List<Employer>)EmployerObjectDataSource.Select();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (empl.Count() == 1)
        {
            Employer employer = empl.First();

            //The GetEmployer method of BLL is called here (WHY????)
            ((RadTextBox)EmployerFormView.Row.FindControl("txtAme")).Text = employer.AME.ToString();
            ((RadTextBox)EmployerFormView.Row.FindControl("txtAfm")).Text = employer.EmplrAFM.ToString();
            ((RadTextBox)EmployerFormView.Row.FindControl("txtName")).Text = employer.EmplrLastName.ToString();
  ...
```

The GetEmployer is shown below:

```
    public List<Employer> GetEmployer(string username, short version)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        List<Employer> employers = (ikaRepository.GetEmployers(username, today, version)).ToList<Employer>();

        Debug.Assert(employers.Count() <= 1, "This is a logical Error - Can we have more than one active Employer records per user?");
        return employers;
    }
```

Here is the question: 
When I attached the debugger, I saw that the `GetEmployer` method of the BLL is called twice. First time on the `.Select()` and second time when I try to get the value of the first field of the `Employer` record.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you bind data in PreRender instead of Load?

Comment: @DmytroRudenko I was trying to work around another problem and left it like this. You are right that Page_Load is more appropriate, however this made no difference to my posted problem.

Comment: maybe you have some sode in getter of employer.AME property? I can't find any other reason why Select() may be called twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not good in English, I apologize, in advance.

You manually bound `FormView` to `ObjectDataSource` in code-behind. So you called `Select` method once in `Page` **Loading** phase (based on current codes).

Have you assigned `"EmployerObjectDataSource"` to `EmployerFormView`'s `DataSourceID` in your markups (ASPX contents), and bind `FormView` to `ObjectDataSource` in `Page` **Event Handling** phase (after `Load` phase), so it call `Select` method once again.

It is better, that you don't manually bind `DataBoundControls` (like `FormView`) to `DataSourceControls` (like `ObjectDataSource`). Instead, you can use `SelectParameters` inside `ObjectDataSource` markup if it needs to pass some data to BLL for selecting/filtering logics.

I think this situation it is what happened. I suggest you should write your markups too.

Another situation is binding one `ObjectDataSource` to more that one `DataBoundControls`.
In this situation, every `DataBoundControls` will call `ObjectDataSource`'s `Select` method on it's binding-time. To handling this situation, you can use caching capabilities of `ObjectDataSource`.

I hope these explanations will be useful.

I suggest you to read these resources before using ASP.NET Data Controls:

1. [ObjectDataSource on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [FormView on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Good luck!

Comment: (+1) You may also mention that `FormView` requires only record or row, instead of many records, so binding to several `ObjectDataSource` controls may cause some conflict.